# How to compile some C code on 64-bit Windows 7 machine using gcc 4.5.3

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to compile a plugin for Stata (a statistical programming language) that is written in C. Its author was able to compile it on other machines using the following commands on a 32-bit PC Windows (using Cygwin):

```
gcc -shared -mno-cygwin stplugin.c strgroup.c -O3 -funroll-loops -o strgroup.PC.Windows.plugin
```

He was also able to compile it on 64-bit Unix with:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -DSYSTEM=OPUNIX stplugin.c strgroup.c -O3 -funroll-loops -o "strgroup.PC (64-bit x86-64).Unix.plugin"
```

And Macintosh OS X with:

```
gcc -bundle -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -DSYSTEM=APPLEMAC stplugin.c strgroup.c -O3 -funroll-loops -o "strgroup.Macintosh.MacOSX.plugin"
```

I am trying to compile it on 64-bit Windows 7 machine using Cygwin 1.7.9-1 and gcc v4.5.3. The mno-cygwin flag is giving me trouble, but I am not able to figure out how to use a mingw-targeted cross-compiler.

Comment: "giving me trouble" is a little vague.

Comment: The message is "gcc: The -mno-cygwin flag has been removed; use a mingw-targeted cross-compiler."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-mno-cygwin` option is [no longer supported](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2010-10/msg00537.html).

Install either of the `mingw-*`, `mingw64-i686-*` or `mingw64-x86_64-*` toolchain (category *Devel* in the Cygwin package manager) to get a proper cross-compiler.

Comment: I already got those installed, but I am confused which flag should I use. The man page for gcc seems to have many options and I am not quite sure which one to use: `-mconsole -mcygwin -mno-cygwin -mdll -mnop-fun-dllimport -mthread -municode -mwin32 -mwindows -fno-set-stack-executable`

Comment: I am an idiot. I misunderstood what you meant. The following code works: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared stplugin.c strgroup.c -O3 -funroll-loops -o strgroup.plugin'.